# I don't care about caching or performance - any reason I shouldn't use embedded CSS?

Tags: html, css

As part of my job I maintain/develop an internal web application.  It has relatively few users and just isn't that big.  I've got a global CSS file that contains some re-used styles, but 90% of my page-specific styles really really ARE page-specific; they are things like pseudo-column widths (a lot of my output is just non-tabular enough to make tables a poor choice).  I have taken to just throwing a <style> block at the top of these pages.

I know this is frowned upon, but every time I read about the reasons for separate CSS files the only one that really stands out is caching.  In this case that doesn't matter; it is WAY down on the list of things I would do if I needed to speed up the application.  Are there any other reasons, or can I stop feeling guilty?

Comment: Stop feeling guilty, life's too short.

Comment: See this: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: you may feel the pain of your ways some day, and then change your mind :)

Comment: Under the "maintainability" pile:  Using grep on a class name is waaaay easier than grepping on individual CSS properties, especially when you have a lot of elements modifying the property you're trying to search for.

Answer (score 7):

> every time I read about the reasons for separate CSS files the only one that really stands out is caching

Really?

Every time I read about their usage, the fact that you can change something in a CSS file and *all pages that include it* will have the change is the most important reason to use them.

Having your CSS centralized is a good thing even if your specific pages have different specific rules. It helps you unify the basic CSS structure across the site and when looking for how a specific effect was achieved it will be easy to locate.

These are all worthy reasons to use CSS files, well above any caching/performance reasons.

Comment: @BoltClock - Does it ever?

Comment: @BoltClock Then you think of the poor developer who will take over after you are long gone.

Comment: @mookamafoob: Not sure what you're driving at.

Comment: That's the thing: I have a lot of CSS that really-really-truly-definitely is only used by one page.  I only want it to be used by that page.  If it were used by a different page I would be upset!  I would have to track down the bug!

As I mentioned above, a lot of my pages have pseudo-tabular layout but don't actually use tables - so I've got a bunch of ol/ul and li items, each containing divs that I want to have a specified width.  The width settings are necessarily different for each page.

Comment: @Alex - That sounds like you are simply not using CSS in a maintainable manner. If each of your pages has a different `id` for the content area, you can target the CSS as much as needed.

Comment: @Oded - that results in a giant file that is actually somewhat MORE difficult to read through (IMO) than just having a &lt;style&gt; block at the top of the page.  It's certainly not different in any meaningful semantic way.

Comment: @AlexGodofsky - It makes it much easier to apply global changes. But of course, it is your site to maintain and your right to do so any way you wish...

Answer (score 2):

I face a similar problem, in that most of my styles are very much page-specific. However, my site is far from small, so I had to find a solution.

What I ended up doing was creating a folder `css/pages`, and naming each CSS file the same as the page that uses it. Then, my PHP "template" can just check `if(file_exists("css/pages/".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])))` and add the relevant `<link/>` tag, resulting in minimal effort on my part.

Just because your site is small is not a valid reason to disregard efficiency, although I have to say I'm a bit of an efficiency nerd so I'll probably be more pedantic over that :p

Ultimately, there's nothing "wrong" with just putting page-specific CSS directly in the page, just make sure that anything that is used on more than one page is in a file so you don't have to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if your app only contain a few web pages(3-5 pages) then you can go ahead define it at the top of the web pages. If your app is going to grow into more that 3-5 web pages then global CSS will help with maintainability and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Makes for cleaner mark-up, quicker load.  Really applies to template and dynamic development.  Don't be afraid to use it.  It's not like you're going over to the dark side.